# Cordova CSP and GCM (fails because online method uses eval in Cordova)

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, eval

I had to add CSP to my app, but I got in trouble.

App is using com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin plugin, that worked just fine, but after adding CSP in console it started to throw this kind of errors:

```
Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source        of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'     https://*.domain.net http://*.domain.net".  cordova.js:1006
processMessage cordova.js:1006
androidExec.processMessages cordova.js:1076
pollOnce cordova.js:944
pollOnceFromOnlineEvent cordova.js:939

processMessage failed: Error: EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because     'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy      directive: "script-src 'self' https://*.domain.net http://*.domain.net".
cordova.js:1044
```

I have looked at processMessage method and it fails at eval method it tries to use (eval(message.slice(1));) it violates CSP.

Question: Is it possible use CSP and register for GCM?

If anyone has done that, please share your methods.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried adding the `unsafe-eval` to your policy as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing)?

Comment: It is absurd if unsafe eval is required for this. Enabling that opens up the app to so many security risks from injection that it would border on irresponsible to load anything from remote locations, such as advertisements.